# ( (Where and Where) OR (Where and Where) ) Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5, where-clause

I am trying to create ( (Where and Where) OR (Where and Where) )  And after a lot of searching I found this

```
    $sender = \App\User::where('username','=',$username)->firstOrFail();
    $receiver = Auth::user();
    $messages = \App\Message::Where(function($query)
                              {
                                  $query->where("sender",$sender->id)
                                        ->where("receiver",$receiver->id);
                              })
                              ->orWhere(function($query)
                              {
                                  $query->Where("sender",$receiver->id)
                                        ->Where("receiver",$sender->id);
                              })
                              ->get();
```

But it's showing me that the **$sender** and the **$receiver** variables are undefined , Any help please , I'm trying to show the messages of the both users, I thought also that I can get the first (where and where) alone and then get the second one then I'll merge them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To use `$send` and `$receiver` within a `Closure` do the following;

```
function ($query) use($sender, $receiver){

}
```

Allowing you to access the variables within the scope of that function.

So your solution becomes;

```
$messages = \App\Message::Where(function($query) use ($sender, $receiver)
                          {
                              $query->where("sender",$sender->id)
                                    ->where("receiver",$receiver->id);
                          })
                          ->orWhere(function($query) use ($sender, $receiver)
                          {
                              $query->Where("sender",$receiver->id)
                                    ->Where("receiver",$sender->id);
                          })
                          ->get();
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the variables through with `use`:

```
$messages = \App\Message::Where(function($query) use ($sender, $receiver)
                          {
                              $query->where("sender",$sender->id)
                                    ->where("receiver",$receiver->id);
                          })
                          ->orWhere(function($query) use ($sender, $receiver)
                          {
                              $query->Where("sender",$receiver->id)
                                    ->Where("receiver",$sender->id);
                          })
                          ->get();
```