# ( (Where and Where) OR (Where and Where) ) CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

This is reference of laravel: [( (Where and Where) OR (Where and Where) ) Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39371276/where-and-where-or-where-and-where-laravel-5-2)

This is my code:

```
$this->db->select('BaseTbl.*');
$this->db->from('tablename as BaseTbl');
// *************** WHERE THIS Based on sendMeetingSchedule = 'YES' ****************
$this->db->where('BaseTbl.companyId', 10);
$this->db->where_not_in('BaseTbl.status', array('Draft'));
$this->db->where('BaseTbl.description !=', '');
$this->db->where('BaseTbl.sendMeetingSchedule', 'Yes');
// *************** OR THIS Based on sendMeetingSchedule = 'NO' ****************
$this->db->or_where('BaseTbl.sendMeetingSchedule', 'No');
$this->db->where('BaseTbl.status', 'Pending Meeting');
$this->db->order_by('BaseTbl.id', 'desc');
```

This is my query output:

```
SELECT `BaseTbl`.* FROM `tablename` as `BaseTbl` WHERE `BaseTbl`.`companyId` = '10' AND `BaseTbl`.`status` NOT IN('Draft') AND `BaseTbl`.`description` != '' AND `BaseTbl`.`sendMeetingSchedule` = 'Yes' OR `BaseTbl`.`sendMeetingSchedule` = 'No' AND `BaseTbl`.`status` = 'Pending Meeting' ORDER BY `BaseTbl`.`id` DESC
```

I want where clause based on sendMeetingSchedule column. If its 'YES' then run upper where clauses otherwise run bottom where clauses in codeigniter.

This is my desired  query output:

```
SELECT `BaseTbl`.* FROM `tablename` as `BaseTbl` WHERE (`BaseTbl`.`companyId` = '10' AND `BaseTbl`.`status` NOT IN('Draft') AND `BaseTbl`.`description` != '' AND `BaseTbl`.`sendMeetingSchedule` = 'Yes') OR (`BaseTbl`.`sendMeetingSchedule` = 'No' AND `BaseTbl`.`status` = 'Pending Meeting') ORDER BY `BaseTbl`.`id` DESC
```

NOTE: Without using custom where clause:

```
$this->db->where('MATCH (field) AGAINST ("value")', NULL, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `group_start()` and `group_end()` for open bracket and close bracket.

```
$this->db->select('BaseTbl.*');
$this->db->from('tablename as BaseTbl');

// *************** WHERE THIS Based on sendMeetingSchedule = 'YES' ****************
$this->db->group_start() // Open bracket;
$this->db->where('BaseTbl.companyId', 10);
$this->db->where_not_in('BaseTbl.status', array('Draft'));
$this->db->where('BaseTbl.description !=', '');
$this->db->where('BaseTbl.sendMeetingSchedule', 'Yes');
$this->db->group_end() // Close bracket;

// *************** OR THIS Based on sendMeetingSchedule = 'NO' ****************
$this->db->or_group_start() // Open bracket;
$this->db->where('BaseTbl.sendMeetingSchedule', 'No');
$this->db->where('BaseTbl.status', 'Pending Meeting');
$this->db->group_end() // Close bracket;
$this->db->order_by('BaseTbl.id', 'desc');
```

NOTE: This is applicable for Codeigniter 3.0.3 or higher

Comment: Wow thanks your code is very easy to use thats what I exactly needed. btw your code is giving output  `( (Where and/or Where) AND (Where and/or Where) ) ` I want `( (Where and/or Where) OR (Where and/or Where) ) ` please update your answer